# SharePoint 2013 workflows, assigning tasks and maintain column metadata

Tags: 2013, workflow, metadata

I have a document library with 3 site columns, these columns contain additional metadata relating to the content and categorisation of the document. This document library has a "publishing" workflow attached to it that when started assigns a task to a user, the assigned user adds additional information to these document columns then submits for publishing.  The last part of the workflow gathers up the metadata and document and copies to another document library and also updates the source library metadata.

The issue I have is that I want to grab the metadata that is already associated to the document before publishing and push it to the new task item.  The user will then see the existing metadata and be able to amend if needed.

I've had a play around with different ways of doing this and although I can bodge it i.e. create a WF on the task list which fires when a item is created it really isn't a durable solution.

Any thoughts on a better way to do this?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this off.  I couldn't find a good solution using the "Assign task" action.  Instead I went back to a simpler workflow and created a custom edit form view for the document library that the user sees when clicking on a link provided by a WF email.  Once the user has updated the document properties another workflow fires and moves copies the document.